# TFS Online and Visual Studio 2013

Tags: visual-studio-2013, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I am trying to automate my builds/releases. I'm using VS 2013 for development and I put my team project on VSTS (Visual Studio Team Services). I downloaded "Build and Release Agent" and installed a private agent on my machine. Agent connected successfully and listening for jobs as well. But when I am trying to create a build from Visual Studio Online it doesn't build and fails. The error that I am getting is

> Error: Visual Studio 2015 is not found. Try again with a version that exists on your build agent machine

Do I need to get Visual Studio 2015? But I don't have a license for that.

Comment: Do you mean it throws error after queue build? Is there build log available? What're task of your build definition? Can you provide the screenshot?

Answer (score 1):

VSTS checks the agent to see what *capabilities* it supports - basically what other dev tools are installed on the agent machine - and it sounds like that's the check that's failing here.

But why not update to Visual Studio 2017, the latest, now? The Community edition is free and quite full featured. I expect you'd be happy going that route.

Comment: Thanks, Bret. I installed VS2017 Community edition and it worked fine for me. I'm grateful.

Answer (score 0):

When you register an agent, Visual Studio Team Services (VSTS) scans the machine to determine which tools are installed and can be used for building software. This can be versions of Visual Studio, Java, NPM etc. This makes up the capabilities of your agent. If you navigate to [https://.visualstudio.com/_admin/_AgentPool?poolId=1&_a=agents](https://%3CYOURACCOUNT%3E.visualstudio.com/_admin/_AgentPool?poolId=1&_a=agents), you can then select your pool and agent (by default, the pool is default and the agent name is your machine name). You can then view the capabilities of the agent like shown here:

[image: Agent Capabilities]

Now when you create a build, each task also has a set of demands. When you queue a build, VSTS looks for an agent that has the right set of capabilities to meet the demands of the build definition. When such an agent cannot be found, you get an error like what you're seeing.

[image: Build demands]

So you've probably added a task that requires VS 2015. Some tasks allow you to specify the VS version you want to use. If that's not possible, you could look into using another task or maybe using one of the free Community Editions to upgrade your machine.

Comment: Thanks, Wouter for the explanation and help. I installed VS2017 Community edition and it worked fine for me. I'm grateful.